# How to read values from SQL into a dict of lis

Tags: python, dataframe, list

I am reading values from SQL server using **pymssql** library using the below code

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, cnxn)
```

This is giving me a df as below

```
addr      port     device_id
==============================
XXX       1001      01
XXX       1001      02
XXX       1001      03
YYY       1001      04
YYY       1001      05
```

Is there a way to convert this df into a dict of list as shown below,

```
{ 
'addr': [XXX, XXX, XXX],
'port': [1001,1001,1001],
'device_id': [01, 02, 03]
},
{
'addr': [YYY,YYY],
'port': [1001,1001],
'device_id': [04, 05]
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), you can use [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) and [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
out = df.groupby('addr').apply(lambda g: g.to_dict('list')).to_list()
```

Output:

```
[{'addr': ['XXX', 'XXX', 'XXX'],
  'port': [1001, 1001, 1001],
  'device_id': [1, 2, 3]},
 {'addr': ['YYY', 'YYY'],
  'port': [1001, 1001],
  'device_id': [4, 5]},
]
```